# Keep the headlines expanded in Org-Mode

Tags: org-mode

I have started using Org-Mode and every time I close my file every headline is collapsed when I reopen it. Is there any way to stop that? I want every headline fully expanded.

Comment: `(setq org-startup-folded nil)`

Comment: Your question heading and body are opposite. Do you want or don't want the full expansion at start-up?

Comment: @kaushalmodi -- If you could please add the alternative approach to your answer -- i.e., `(setq org-startup-folded nil)` -- that would be greatly appreciated.  One answer is sufficient.  I added a 1+ as to your request for clarification from the original poster.

Comment: @kaushalmodi sorry my bad! I will edit!

Comment: [The default was changed recently](https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/src/master/etc/ORG-NEWS#L167), so that (unless you specify otherwise) all the headlines are expanded: that was deemed friendlier to beginners, while old-timers (or people who have read this question and/or the relevant section of the manual as in Kaushal's answer) know what to do to change it if they don't like it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is possible to set the [Initial Visibility](http://orgmode.org/manual/Initial-visibility.html#Initial-visibility) per org file. You can make the org file show all the headings expanded at start-up by using

```
#+STARTUP: showeverything
```

As @lawlist mentioned in the comments, you can also set this option to be effective globally by putting the below in your emacs init:

```el
(setq org-startup-folded nil)
```