# Remember expansion of headlines in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode

In my org file, I have a lot of headlines that I'd like to keep folded most of the time - and some that I want expanded, but the state of each expanded headline is lost when I close emacs.

Is there a way to restore the state upon re-opening the file?

PS: I'm not looking for the default expansion state as in [Keep the headlines expanded in Org-Mode](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/9709/keep-the-headlines-expanded-in-org-mode), nor I want to set the default visibility of each headline manually through properties - I want to remember the state of the whole file, heterogenous as it may be.

Comment: There is not a way to do this that exists in org-mode. You would have to save the state to a file, setup some file variables to reload the state when the org file is opened, and probably a hook function to save the state on exiting. You can get the state with (org-outline-overlay-data) and restore it with (org-set-outline-overlay-data).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd need to persist the result of `org-outline-overlay-data` on save/exit, then restore it on open/start with `org-set-outline-overlay-data`.

You can see an example of this in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666862/org-mode-go-back-from-sparse-tree-to-previous-visibility/44158824#44158824).

(Sorry this should've been a comment but I don't have the rep yet.)

Comment: Seems like there is no way to even do this anymore, due to recent changes. Very unfortunate.